# Select first DataList item by default

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

Is it possible to select a datalist's item (say first item) by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the DataList's [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.selectedindex.aspx)="0"

Comment: Yes. That would work. But I was curious to know if something like FirsOrDefault could be done here, like we do in LINQ.